# How to upload a file in wear OS to the cloud using wifi?

Tags: android-studio, cloud, wifi, wear-os, user-data

I am trying to create an app for wear OS in which user data is stored as a text file. Now, I want to collect this data and figure out a method using which the user uploads this data to the cloud using the watch wifi and I can collect it somehow. Is there any method to do this? Any help would be highly appreciated.